# Is $0 \to p \to R_p \to Frac(R/p) \to 0$ exact sequence?

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, localization

I have got the following task on my commutative algebra course:

Let us have a prime ideal $p$ in ring $R$. Consider the exact sequence $0 \to p \to R \to R/p \to 0$.

Now let's localize the sequence. It should stay exact. Which exact sequence we obtain.

I suspect $0 \to p \to R_p \to Frac(R/p) \to 0$

I denote by $Frac$ the ring obtained from the given by localization over all nonzerodivisors.

Is my suspicion true and why? I'm not sure with the result of localization in the last term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When considering the exact sequence $0 \to p \to R \to R/p \to 0$ and

localizeing this sequence, we have the exact sequence $0 \to pR_p \to R_p \to (R/p)_p \to 0$. Thus we have $\frac{R_p}{pR_p}\cong (R/p)_p$ and since $\frac{R_p}{pR_p}$ is a field ($pR_p$ is a maximal ideal), $(R/p)_p$ is a field, and hence $(R/p)_p=Frac(R/p)$. Thus $$0 \to pR_p \to R_p \to Frac(R/p)\to 0$$ is an  exact sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The last term is correct. The Frac over a domain is the localisation on the prime ideal $0$. You can also verify that the localisation "commutes" with the quotient operation so $(\frac{R}{p})_{\bar{p}}=(\frac{R}{p})_{\bar{0}}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{(R)_p}{p(R)_p}$ but $(R)_p$ is a local ring so you will find your "Frac" and you should be able to write your exact sequence. What is $p$ localised as a $R$ module?...